# proof of $\mathbb E[g(X)]=\int g(x)f_X(x)dx$

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X$ a r.v. I have to prove that $$\mathbb E[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)f_X(x)dx$$
if $X$ is continuous and $$\mathbb E[g(X)]=\sum_{k\in \mathcal D}g(k)f_X(k),$$
if $X$ is discrete.

---

**Attempts**

- If $X$ is continuous, then $F(x):=\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}$ is derivable and incresing. Therefore, $$\mathbb E[g(X)]\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R}g(X)d\mathbb P=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)dF(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\frac{dF(x)}{dx}dx\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)f_X(x)dx.$$

**Q1)** Does it work ? I'm not sure that I can do $(*)$. It looks intuitive, but I can't justify it properly.

- Let $\mathcal D$ countable such that $\mathbb P\{X\in \mathcal D\}=1$. Then $$\mathbb E[g(X)]=\sum_{\omega \in\Omega }X(\omega )\mathbb P\{g(X(\omega ))=k\}=\sum_{k\in \mathcal D}g(k)f_X(k),$$
  where I proved the last equality brut force.

**Q2)** But is there a straightforward argument using measure theory ?

Comment: Indeed, the equality before $(*)$ should be prove rigorously, because to write $\int g(x)dF(x)=\int g(x)\frac{dF}{dx}dx$ doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Surb: I corrected it. But how can I prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

If the measure $\mathbb{P}$ induced by $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$ then then [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) asserts that exists $f_X$ such that for every $E$ measurable:
$$ \mathbb{P}(E) = \int _E f_X \mathrm{d}x $$
Since $X$ is continuous it induced a non negative measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that's absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, so the Radon-Nikodym derivative exists and you use it on the equality $(*)$.